# Analysis of multiple response question

Tags: distributions

I asked a question to school children to mention to me the critical times for handwashing. the maximum responses were 3. I want to analyse this data in such a way that i can capture the number of children who mentioned 3 times, the number who mentioned two times and the number that mentioned 1 time.  How do i go about it?

Comment: You might like to browse some of the questions and answers tagged ordered-logit on this site for further enlightenment,

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case a ordered response model like the ordered probit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit) or ordered logit could be a good solution because with the count data you have a natural oder in the responses. In general, the idea of ordered resoponse model is that in the background a latent continous model works $$ Y^{*}=X\beta+u$$ and that the realizations you see belong to some intervalls $I$ of $Y^*$. I.e. $Y=1$ if $Y\in I_1$,  $Y=2$ if $Y\in I_2$ and  $Y=3$ if $Y\in I_3$. Then you can estimate the effects of covariates on the probability of having a response being equal $1,2$ or $3$.